# Syntax TCL: missing operator at _@_

Tags: syntax, tcl, tk-toolkit

I am trying to get the max of a list, the list may contain a zero, 0. In Tcl 8.5, when i run:

```
set x {-5 -4 -3 -2 -1 0 1 2 3 4 5}
set maxx [expr max($x)]
set minx [expr min($x)]
puts "$minx $maxx"
```

I get the error:

```
missing operator at _@_
in expression "max(-5 -4 -3 -2 -1 _@_0 1 2 3 4 5)"
(parsing expression "max(-5 -4 -3 -2 -1 0 1...")
invoked from within
"expr "max($x)""
invoked from within
"set maxx [expr "max($x"]"
```

I've tried ever syntactical variation and resource I could find.

As a work around, I will just use lsort and take the first/last elements of that list, but I really want to know what I am doing wrong here :/ Thanks.

Comment: An aside from the question, is [http://wiki.tcl.tk/](http://wiki.tcl.tk/) down for other people too? I've tried a few different access points and can't get to it as of this afternoon PST.

Comment: As of now, it seems to redirect to a torrent site.

Comment: thanks, happen know of any other good tcl resource alternatives? driving me crazy right now being able to have a solid resource

Comment: Most of the good resources I know about are in the same domain set. There used to be a lot more around; let's hope they are able to take the domains back.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tcl expressions work a bit different, you can't directly stuff a list into it and expect it to work.

I suggest you use `::tcl::mathfunc::max` directly, with argument expansion (`{*}`):

```
set maxx [::tcl::mathfunc::max {*}$x]
set minx [::tcl::mathfunc::min {*}$x]
```

But if you still want to use `expr`, you can try to create a valid expression with join:

```
set maxx [expr "max([join $x ,])"]
set minx [expr "min([join $x ,])"]
```

But this has a poor performance and can be exploited (code injection), consider this input for `x`: `{-1 {[puts "Not good"; exit]} 2}`

Comment: Any chance you could provide some more resources/links explaining the syntax of "::" and {*} argument expansion? Thanks a ton!

Comment: `::` is the namespace separator, and all functions that `expr` know of are Tcl commands in the namespace `tcl::mathfunc`. `{*}` is for argument expansion; basically convert `someproc {*}{a b c}` into `someproc a b c`, expanding the argument that follows (without a space) to more than 1 argument.

Answer (score 3):

A bit of elaboration. Please let me know if it's unsuitable.

To the interpreter, the invocation `foo {{a a a} {b b} c}` has a single argument (consisting of three items or words), and `foo {a a a} {b b} c` has three arguments (each consisting of three, two or one items or words). As long as the invocation of a command is a proper list, the interpreter doesn't care what the arguments consist of or how many they are. The commands, otoh, typically care about the number and contents of the arguments.

This means that we may have to be sneaky. Can we assign `foo` and `bar` to the variable `x`? Yes, but not as `set x foo bar`, because the `set` command (not the interpreter) requires one or two arguments (the variable name and zero or one values). If we invoke it as `set x {foo bar}` or `set x [list foo bar]`, we get the correct number of arguments.

At other times we have a bunch of values packed up in a list, but the command requires each value to be in its own argument (your `max` command is an example). `::tcl::mathfunc::max {2 3 1}` fails since the command recognizes that it has been given a single value, and that value should conform to the format of a double precision floating point number. In this cases, we do the approximate inverse of packing up values in a list: we unpack a list into arguments. `::tcl::mathfunc::max {*}{2 3 1}` is, to the interpreter, the same as writing `::tcl::mathfunc::max 2 3 1`, which works.

(If `foo` is a list of zero or one items, `set x {*}$foo` will always work. Think about it.)

Invoking the `max` command as a function inside an `expr` expression is another can of worms. Generally speaking, it's (imho) better to use `expr` for simpler, fixed expressions (e.g. `expr {max($a,$b)}`) and find f.i. the maximum value of a list by invoking the command without involving `expr`.